# How to combine lines with different starting points in chartjs

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to set up a chart with two or later on multiple lines in one chart.
The data is collected from a logging database and has different starting points.

The example:
I tracked the result of a search for item 123 with search term ABC starting from June 1st each day.

On June 3rd I added another tracked search for item 123 with search term XYZ.

Now I want to display a line chart starting from June 1st with both tracked searches, each as an own line. One line starting on June 1st, the other starting on June 3rd.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making a scatter graph instead, with a list of x/y coordinates for each point. Either that, or put in dummy data point for your missing data.